# how to achieve mod_rewrite functionality in text editor's search and replace?

Tags: regex, text-editor

```
RewriteRule ^/?page/?([a-zA-Z0-9,-]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

is it possible for a text editor to find and replace a string in a manner as how apache's mod_rewrite does it? i mean for example, in a text-file, i'd like to enclose all email addresses inside double qoutes,
by inputting `[a-zA-Z_]@[a-zA-Z-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]+` in the "find what" field 
and `"$1"` in the "replace with" field, i get all email addresses replaced with literally a $1, but i wanted the original value just to be appended and preceeded by double qoutes?

or are there any easier approach over the problem ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different text editors handle the replacement value in different ways.  Some use the `$1` as you have shown, others use `\1`.  There is also at times special tokens for 'the entire match.'  TextPad, for example, will use `&` to indicate the entire matched input.  It might be best to consult the regex help supplied (I hope) with your editor.